# How to control Image selection Event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

can anyone tell me about how to control image selection event. For example like I want my program to only select `.jpg` and `.png` format and for rest, at the time of selection it will show an error message.

Comment: dup? [trigger file upload event
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021335/trigger-file-upload-event)

Comment: @LeiYang not getting properly

Comment: Pls post your model and how you use in view?

Comment: which part not?

Comment: @LeiYang Question isn't a duplicate of other link you provided pls recheck

Comment: @LeiYang actually i have an upload button and at the time of image selection i just want to have like i only want to select only jpg and png image and for rest it will show an error

Comment: Check [data annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4) and [client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944/how-do-i-validate-the-file-type-of-a-file-upload)